# Rave Report v9 - как перенести на новую строку вывод данных в DataMemo?

Tags: delphi, ravereport

Есть строка:
`"серия" & passport_series & "№" & passport_number & "выдан" & organization & passport_date`
Вот не пойму, как в компоненте DataMemo сделать\настроить перенос данных на новую строку?
Допустим "выдан", из примера, писать уже с новой строки.
В своих рамках, у компонента, перенос работает, но хотелось бы какого-то более цивилизованного форматирования данных.